# Where can I find a good iPhone/GWT/AppEngine example?

Tags: iphone, google-app-engine, gwt

These seem like a great combination--I'd expect to see more on at least GWT/iPhone integration, but there isn't much.

I've looked through the reader example that Google made, but it doesn't seem to take advantage of many of the iPhone features.

I was wondering if anyone knew of a tutorial/resource that showed how to use things like location, orientation, stretch/squeeze and various iPhone-specific controls--as well as integration with services like Google maps.

It would be nice if it also used AppEngine, but that is pretty easy to integrate later if not.

Perhaps I'm asking for too much, but I'd even settle for a very technical blog that focused on these platforms...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have developed a GPS App for iPhone/Android with GWT and AppEngine ([m.geotako.com](http://m.geotako.com)):

Technical Info:

- Back-end using Google AppEngine cloud infrastructure
- Front-end using Google Web Toolkit which can run on both iPhone 
  Safari and Android Chrome (also other desktop browsers)
- GWT based internationalization
- Integrated with Facebook Connect for wall posting
- Using Google Maps API for reverse geocoding (retrieve your    address
  automatically when you add    a new 
  location)
- HTML5 based Geolocation for tracking your location with GPS
- HTML5 based Web Database for storing local information in the browser

Features:

- Discover interesting locations around you with beautiful photos
- Share your journey with friends by checking-in to locations around you
- Grabbing mayorship of a location when you checkin frequently
- Post to Facebook wall when you checkin
- Locate where your friends have been to
- Add new locations with photos
- A ranking showing the top travelers with the highest number of mayorships
- Support English, Traditional Chinese and Simplified Chinese

You may try it here: m.geotako.com

The app can also be found in Google App Engine Applications Gallery

Comment: Can you share any advice on getting started? Is there some sort of tutorial on how to use GWT for mobile apps? Thanks!

Comment: Nice app.  Any of it open source?

Answer (score 2):

GWT doesn't actually support most mobile browser features (touch events, geolocation, orientation, etc.) out of the box, but the [gwt-mobile-webkit](http://code.google.com/p/gwt-mobile-webkit/) project aims to add those features, specifically for the iPhone browser.  They even have some demos and example code on their project home page.

Comment: Good reference.  I was hoping that the state of GWT/iPhone integration was further along than this, but I'll take what I can get.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked through the Apple sample code? They wrote example programs for most of the iPhone specific features.

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/

Comment: That's good advice but I was really hoping for a GWT solution... I'm no where near ready to implement my own GWT objects for new Javascript methods.